# Action is not loaded within extension plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using `wordpress 5.2.3` furthermore I am trying to code my own custom tag for the plugin `mailster 2.4.4`, a newsletter plugin for wordpress.

The [plugin documentation says](https://kb.mailster.co/add-custom-dynamic-tags-to-your-newsletter/) that I should just add an action `mailster_add_tag` to the `functions.php`.

However, I am trying to create my own plugin as more functionality/complexity  will be added in the future:

My `newsletter.php`:

```
<?php
/**
Plugin Name: Newsletter Extension
description: Mailster Newsletter Extension
Version: 1.0
Author: Batman
License: GPLv2 or later
Text Domain: newsletter
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

class Newsletter {

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        //  constants.
        define( '_FILE', __FILE__ );
        define( '_DIR', trailingslashit( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) );
        define( '_VERSION', '0.0.1' );
        register_activation_hook( basename( _DIR ) . '/' . basename( _FILE ), array( $this, 'activate' ) );
        add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'includes' ) );
    }
    /**
     * Called on plugin activation
     */
    public function activate() {
        $this->includes();
        $this->addCustomTags();

        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
    /**
     * Includes.
     */
    public function includes() {
        include_once( _DIR . 'includes/DailyTemplate.php' );
    }
    /**
     * Includes.
     */
    public function addCustomTags() {
        DailyTemplate::addMyTag();
    }
}
new Newsletter();
```

Within my `includes/DailyTemplate.php`:

```
<?php

class DailyTemplate {

    public function __construct() { }

    public function addMyTag() {
        if ( function_exists( 'mailster_add_tag' ) ) {
            mailster_add_tag( 'coupon', function( $option, $fallback, $campaignID = null, $subscriberID = null ) {

                // make sure the subscriber ID is set
                if ( ! is_null( $subscriberID ) ) {
                    return get_subscribers_coupon( $subscriberID );
                }

                // return the fallback "NOCOUPONCODE4U"
                return $fallback;
            } );
        }
    }

    function get_subscribers_coupon( $subscriber_id ) {
        $seed = AUTH_SALT;
        $length = 10;
        $code = substr( strtoupper( base_convert( md5( $seed . $subscriber_id ), 16, 36 ) ), 0, $length );
        return $code;
    }

}
new DailyTemplate();
```

When running the above code, I do not get any error.

However, it seems to me that the plugin is not loaded because - as the documentation stated - there is no tag in the [dropdown list of the editor](https://kb.mailster.co/add-custom-dynamic-tags-to-your-newsletter/). (see picture on page)

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong to load the tag? Do I use the wrong hook?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you're calling a static method:

```
public function addCustomTags() {
    DailyTemplate::addMyTag();
}
```

So, it's better to declare this method as static, as calling non-static methods statically is deprecated, so to be like that:

```
public static function addMyTag() { //.....
```

in the "addMyTag()" method you call a member method inside your class, so you should call your method this way:

```
return self::get_subscribers_coupon( $subscriberID );
```

the last thing you should also declare the "get_subscribers_coupon()" method as a static method since we call it statically:

```
public static function get_subscribers_coupon( $subscriber_id ) { //....
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

Here `DailyTemplate::addMyTag();` you are calling a method which is static and is accessible without the creation of an object. So you may declare it as static method. Calling non-static methods statically is deprecated since PHP 7. Declare as

```
public static function addMyTag
```

and check if it works or not

Comment: Thx for your reply! I put it now into my theme's `function.php` and it worked. However, when changing it in the plugin it doesn`t work. Any suggestions what might be the reason?